# Todd Coxeter Algorithm

Tags: group-theory

Any one can assist me in finding the cosets of a subgroup of a group by using **Todd Coxeter** algorithm. I am having difficulties in the defining and scanning of elements. For example in the group of $S_3$ and alternating group, $A_5$.

Comment: For which subgroup $H$ of $S_3$, do u want to find $[S_3:H]$??

Comment: If we take subgroup H=<x: x^5=1> of A5.

Comment: We know that $A_5=\langle a,b\mid a^2=b^3=(ab)^5=1\rangle$. Is this $H$ like this $H=\langle (ab)^5=1\rangle$ or ????

Comment: What is that $x$ in $H$. Indeed, we should know that $x$ with respect of $A_5$ generators.

Comment: H is the subgroup of order 5 generated by b where A5 is <a,b: a^3= b^5=(ab)^2>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you can use my computational way as you wanted. The desire index, however it could be found by another ways, is $12$.

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain me how you start defining elements in this method because always alter for different subgroups of a group?

Comment: @Siddiqua: Believe me or not, it is a bit hard for me to explain it here cause it needs good English ability. I just got it from one of E.F.Robertson's student and use the tables to find the index. But I can suggest you to have look at this book `Algebraic Structure by C.F.Gardiner`. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for this reference. However, is it possible for you to explain the circles with numberings in this table that what does it shows. Otherwise no problem, I will try to understand it as far as I can.

Comment: @Siddiqua: In fact in that situations you are face to some coincidences while working with numbers. For instance you see `2b3b4b5b6b2` or `1a2a3a1`. Indeed, we have here something like a permutation.

Comment: Could you please show me the Coset table for a subgroup of order 3 for the same group as cited above, so that I could compare my results with it for defining and scanning elements?

Comment: I calculated 5 cosets of H of order 3 of a subgroup of A5. Is that correct?

Comment: @Siddiqua: I should have the table the same as latest table in the picture above. Without it, I cannot check the processes.

Answer (score 0):

[image: @B.S. Is this coset table correct for Subgroup H=<a,a^3=1> of Alternating group 5 ?]

@B.S. Is this coset table correct for Subgroup H= of Alternating group 5 ?

Comment: However, in Gap it shows me of index 20, if yes then why, where is the mistake.

Comment: Why is 3a = 2 or 5a=3? I conclude 1a=1. I define 2=1b, 3=2b, 4=3b, 5=4b. I conclude 5b=1, 2a=5. At this point I have no deductions available, and have the following undefined: 3a, 4a, 5a. One of those would be defined to be 6, and I would continue.

Comment: @Jac Schmidt, this is what I am understanding how is the defining and scanning elements differ for distinc subgroups of a group.